# Git range-diff throws segmentation fault

Tags: git

Suddenly

```
git range-diff <range1> <range2>
```

shows

> Segmentation fault

Previously it showed the differences in the two ranges of commits.

Experimenting with different git versions, ranges, workdirs, and colleagues connecting to my machine led me to believe  that the problem is specific to git version 2.23.0.windows and some of my branches in the companies repository.

I am using git for windows.

- Version 2.21.0.windows.1 (64-bit)
  Works for me, for my colleague connecting to my workdir; for all version ranges including the problematic one.
- Version 2.23.0.windows.1 (both 64-bit and 32-bit)
  Produce a Segmentation fault when either my or my colleague requests the problematic version range or a different version range in my part of the project in my work directory of in a freshly cloned one.
- Version 2.23.0.windows.1 (64-bit)
  DOES work for other version ranges (up to now, tests with smaller commit ranges that are not related to my work succeeded).

Other git commands have no problem with my work dir.  As fas as I know, only git and sourcetree have modified my git work dir.

I there something I should take into account when doing `git range-diff` on a workdir or on a ranges of commits?  What things should I look for?  How can I repaire the broken ranges?  Why does version 2.21.0.windows.1 work while version 2.23.0.windows.1 does not?

Comment: Consider just reporting this to the git developer mailing list. "Segmentation fault" is _always_ a programming error – even if the program is used incorrectly it should show a normal error message instead of crashing.